# Почему метод слушателя выполняется при входе в активность автоматически?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Создаю spinner. Подключаю его к массиву данных с помощью ArrayAdapter

```
spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<Lesson> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Lesson.lesons);
spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Всё работает.

Вешаю на него слушатель для обработки нажатий.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ChoiseLesson.this, AutoChoisePupile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }
```

Почему-то метод onItemSelected выполняется как только открывается активити со spinner и я сразу попадаю в следующую активити. spinner даже на экране не появляется. Почему так происходит? Подскажите, в чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Наверное вы устанавливаете какой-то элемент выбранным по-умолчанию: `spinner.setSelection()`? Это приводит к вызову слушателя, сделайте это до его установки.

Comment: нет, не устанавливаю. Уже прочёл на некоторых сайтах люди тоже спрашивают об этом же. И им предлагают сделать первую запись пустой или создать счётчик который будет определять первый запуск или не первый. Но мне кажется это странно. Неужели разработчики могли так странно сделать обработчик?

Comment: Спиннер должен выбрать и отобразить по умолчанию что-то из списка, вот и срабатывает чтобы вас информировать. Выбирайте за него до подключения слушателя, либо игнорируйте это срабатывание любым удобным способом.

Comment: Понял. Попробую